# Getting last character in cout

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is very simple but how do I get the last character sent to stdout? If i have a program like

```
int main() {
   cout << "T";
   get_last_char(); // Returns "T"
   return 0;
}
```

how would I make the `get_last_char` function?

Comment: @NathanPierson: A possible solution would be to derive from `std::ostream`, add the method to the derived class, and switch `std::cout` to use that. All doable. A bit of a pain though.

Comment: This isn't a simple problem. I suspect it's an impossible problem if you don't remember the last written character yourself. `ostream cannot be read from and doesn't give access to the output buffer. If there is a buffer at all.

Comment: @user4581301: I think it can be accomplished on the lines I suggest. Although my argument is considerably weakened by my refusal to attempt it!

Comment: That was a too-literal crap comment on my part. My point was you can't do it with `ostream` and you'd have to write code that remembers the character yourself. If that's a wrapper around `cout` or a replacement for `cout`, groovy. But you can't do it with `cout`.